# How to pass parameter to controller using actionlink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, actionlink

I need to pass a view data(integer) to another controller.

This is what i tried;

```
@Html.ActionLink("Get Location", "Index", "Map", new { Id=@item.Id},null)
```

i need to pass this information to "Map" Controller's Index action method;

```
  public ActionResult Index(int? i)
    {
        var Id = from o in db.Objects where o.Id == i select o;
        return View(Id);
    }
```

but the parameter doesn't get pass...is this the way to pass the parameter??When i put a break point i found that int? i is null..why is that??

Comment: Because `"id" != "i"`.  Where in the world would the value of `i` come from?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The parameter you're passing is Id, but your parameter in your action is i.

Rename i to Id.

```
Html.ActionLink("Get Location", "Index", "Map", new { id=@item.Id},null)


public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
    var Id = from o in db.Objects where o.Id == id select o;
    return View(Id);
}
```